# php convert images and upload to amazon s3

Tags: php, file-upload, amazon-s3

I am looking for a best practice while uploading images to amazon s3 server and serving from there.

We need four different sizes of an image. So just after image upload we convert the image and scale in 4 different widths and heights. And then we send them to the amazon s3 using official php api.

```
// ...
// image conversions, bucket setting, s3 initialization etc.

$sizes= array("", "48", "64", "128");

foreach($sizes as $size) {
    $filename = $upload_path.$dest_file.$size.$ext;
    $s3->batch()->create_object($bucket, , array(
                'fileUpload' => $filename,
                'acl' => AmazonS3::ACL_PUBLIC,
            ));
}
```

But for a 1M image the client sometimes wait up to 30 seconds which is a very long time.

Instead of sending images immediately to S3, it may be better to add them to a job queue. But the user should see the uploaded image immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply achieve that by queuing the files, in for example: a database, and then running a cron job, or having a constantly running php script.
If you say you want the users to see the images instantly, should they see them instantly on S3?

Comment: Our webserver can serve but we need some more complexity in php code, image uploaded status will be kept in db. It seems the only solution for the time being, though.

Comment: Well, how about you process the image on your server, add it to the queue database, display it to the user and then run a background task uploading it to S3?

Comment: Yes, a field in images table should be added to check if it's uploaded yet and set its address accordingly.

Comment: can anyone explain this part of the process please "add it to the queue database"